# Align text at the top center of div and button at the end

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a div container like this:

```
<div class="text-offer_dos">
       <div class="centrar">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor!</h3>
        <h5></h5>
        <p class="text"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</b></p>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-deal"  itemprop="potentialAction" data-codigo="sieteporseis">Donec vitae</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I wanna set the text at the **top center** of the div and the button at the end.

This does not work - here is what I tested:

```
.centrar {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0, 0.5);
    height: 390px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}
```

I need to make this touching CSS only, not HTML.

Comment: Can you explain "button at the end"?

Also, when you have a question regarding the layout, it's always better to draw it out in paint or something so that it helps us understand.

Comment: there are two item inside div , a text and a button, i wanna text to be at the top center and the button at the end footer. how to achieve it from css only?? Harshal parekh

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.centrar {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0, 0.5);
    height: 390px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.centrar > button.btn:last-child{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="text-offer_dos">
       <div class="centrar">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor!</h3>
        <h5></h5>
        <p class="text"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</b></p>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-deal"  itemprop="potentialAction" data-codigo="sieteporseis">Donec vitae</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a *column flexbox* and center it horizontally using `align-items: center` and push the button to the bottom using `margin-top: auto` - see demo below:

```css
.centrar {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 390px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* column direction */
  align-items: center;
}

.centrar button { /* This pushes the button to the bottom*/
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-offer_dos">
  <div class="centrar">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor!</h3>
    <h5></h5>
    <p class="text"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</b></p>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-deal" itemprop="potentialAction" data-codigo="sieteporseis">Donec vitae</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @harry check this out by running the code snippet above and let me know your thoughts, thanks!